# NSTimer on a label

Tags: time, label, nstimer

im working with iphone sdk and i got to show a label when the user clik a button but after some time the label deseapear, can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use NSObject's `performSelector: withObject: afterDelay:` for that - it will setup NSTimer that performs selector for you. In button click handler:

```
...
myLabel.hidden = NO;
[self performSelector:@selector(hideView:) withObject:myLabel afterDelay:3];
...

- (void) hideView:(UIView*)inView{
   // You can also add animation here
   view.hidden = YES;
}
```

Note, that it is not guaranteed that `hideView:` will get called exactly after 3 sec.

Comment: Don't forget to put a checkmark on the answer so that Vladimir gets reputation points.